# What is a lifetime of object?

Tags: c

In this example, what will be difference if variable `string_a` is declared as
`static` variable ?

```
const char *pString;
void first(void)
{
    const char string_a[] = " First string ";
    pString =(char *)string_a;
}
void second(void)
{
    const char string_b[] = " Second string ";
    pString =(char *)string_b;
}
int main()
{   
    first();
    second();
    printf("%s\n", pString);
}
```

- What determined a lifetime of object in C  ?
- What is difference between *global* and *file* scope of variables ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632120/scope-vs-life-of-variable-in-c

Comment: *"Lifetime of object"*? What do you mean? C has no objects.

Comment: To elaborate on m0skit0, this question is ambiguous because C has no objects. For example, when you talk about the  lifetime of `string_a`, it's not clear whether you mean the lifetime of the pointer itself or the lifetime of the thing it points to. Asking vague questions tends to get you confusing answers.

Comment: @m0skit0 Ever had a look at the C standard and its rationale? Look [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf).

Comment: @m0skit0: Actually, the spec (C99 at least) does deal with objects, these being defined as "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent
values"

Comment: @glglgl Oh thanks, didn't know about this definition of *object*. Pretty confusing to use the same terminology for totally different things...

Comment: @m0skit0 C++ is a different language so it is free to use any terminology differently from C. However, in this case, it mostly doesn't. The definition of an object in C++ is "a region of storage", very similar to the C definition. An object in C++ can have a user-defined type (e.g. a `class`) or it can have primitive type (e.g. `float` or `int`) or it can have an array type. In the C++ world the word "object" is often used as a shorthand for "`class` object", but that is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kinds of `static` in play here: `static` in the global scope in a file, and `static` inside a function.

The former declares internal linkage for the object, which means that it is only accessible inside the file. These objects are created on [bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) before `main()` is entered. That memory area is always `memset` to all zeros before `main()` runs.

The default for objects created outside function scope is being *global* (external linkage), meaning they can be accessed from other compilation units using the `extern` keyword.

`static` inside a function means that the object exists from the first time the function is called until the program ends.

Illustration:

```
int external_linkage;
static int internal_linkage;

void foo()
{
    static int static_in_function;
}
```

All three variables are *guaranteed* to have a value of `0` when the program runs, unlike stack and heap variables.

Answer (score 2):

Static variables have `file scope` with `internal linkage`. This means that these variables cannot be accessed from other translation units.

Global variables also have `file scope` but with `external linkage`. This means that these variables can be accessed from other translation units as well.

string_a is a local variable defined inside a function. If it is made as static, it will come into existence once the function is called, and will exist until the program ends (whereas non-static local variables stop existing as soon as the function ends).

Answer (score 0):

Global means you can access that variable in another file by using `extern` keyword. File scope means, that variable is not visible to other files.
In c, By default every global variable have global scope. If anyone wants to make global variable invisible to other files they define global variable with `static` keyword. `static` keyword converts global scope to file scope.

Answer (score -1):

Static variables in functions are confined to scope. This means that these variables cannot be accessed from other functions but unlike local variable it's not destroyed after scope and will remain till end of program

Global variables have file scope but those are accessible from other files as well provided
`extern` keyword is used. `static` in global scope in File confines variable to file only.

Comment: C does indeed have something called objects, only it's something different from the *object* in OOP. An *object* in C is defined as **region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values**.

Comment: Edited my answer. I didn't know.