# Printing the int pointer contents always print -2

Tags: c

Why does the last printf output `-2`?
Isn't it supposed to output `2`?
Is there an explanation for this?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void foo(int **);

int main()
{
     int x=20;
     int *p;

     p=&x;
     printf("%d\n",&x); 
     printf("%d\n",p); 
     printf("%d\n",&p); 
     foo(&p);
     printf("%d\n",p); 
     printf("main%d\n",*p);
}

void foo(int **p)
{
     int j=2;
     printf("%d\n",p); 
     printf("%d\n",*p);
     *p=&j;
     printf("%d\n",*p);
     printf("%d\n",**p);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `2`, not `-2`.

Comment: yes i am also getting `2`.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", &x);` is invalid. You must use `%p` for pointers.

Comment: am working on visual studio 2008,it gives -2

Comment: Using the wrong format for printf is undefined behavior. Size of pointer is not always the same as int, esp. in 64-bit systems and Harvard architecture

Answer (score 2):

Your `int j=2;` is local to function `foo`.

You are accessing it after the function returns leading to [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and thus may print `2` or some other value.

If you change `int j = 2` to `static int j = 2` **in your example** then you can always expect output of 2.

Comment: even if i use any other value for j the outout is -2 only.
Any reason for that.

Comment: Exactly my point. You can think of this as, in function foo, you gave life to a variable `j` and value of 2 and kept the address of var `j`. After the function ends, `j` is dead (for detail read about [life and scope of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632120/scope-vs-life-of-variable-in-c)). Because there is nothing like `j` any more you are pointing to something else which may print a value of `2` or something else. It may be different on different OS, compilers etc so even if it works as intended on some target, this is **not** the right way to do things.